# Iteration for "Selection by Location" in ArcGIS modelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iteration

I have a featuredataset of 50 Features which are supposed to have intersection with some lines and their Buffers which are in different feature classes. I have created a separate GDB for the Buffers and would like to define an Iteration in the modelbuilder which can read each feature and intersect it with all Buffers and create a new feature out of it.

I used to work with Iteration for feature classes but it is not applicable for "selection by Location".

Could you assist me how can I define such iteration for my model.

Comment: What do you mean by  not applicable for "selection by Location". Are you using Make Feature Layer before Select by Location?

Comment: "Iterate Feature Selection" will exec makefeaturelayer for you. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_DBDEB1775AAE42F683B46752BB2CC0EF

Comment: Than you very much for your guidance. I did not know taht I hvae to create a layer and now it works nicely